# Conditional Format when another cell is boolean true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a Table, I want the "NP Buyback Cost" to be highlighted if the column preceding it evaluates to TRUE.

[image]

Seems like this should be easy but am not getting it done using either "TRUE" or 1 as the test.
[image]

What is the fix?

Comment: Try `=K3` It is already true and while TRUE evaluates to 1 when used mathematically, you are directly comparing a boolean to **1** without conversion. This can be observed on the worksheet by putting TRUE in a cell (e.g. K3) and putting `=K3=1` in another cell. If want to perform more work than is absolutely necessary, use `=K3+0=1`.

Comment: perfect. if you want to make that an answer I'd be happy to make it official. thanks!

Comment: =K3=TRUE should have worked (unless you were actually putting in the quotes =K3="TRUE" which would try and compare it to a character string not a logical value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a boolean TRUE is mathematically equivalent to 1 when used in an equation, it is not equal to 1 without conversion.

In any two cells you can proof this with the following two formulas.

```
=K3=1        ◄ resolves to False since TRUE is not equal to 1 without conversion
=(K3+0)=1    ◄ resolves to TRUE since adding 0 to a boolean converts it to a number
```

No conversion or comparison is actually necessary since K3 is already a boolean value. The most efficient formula is simply,

```
=K3
```

fwiw, a boolean True is the equivalent of -1 in VBA; not 1 as it is on a worksheet. In both cases, False resolves as zero once converted.

Comment: and (FWIW) coming from the flip side, number to Boolean,  0 is FALSE and all other numbers are TRUE. 17, -42, 3.5 will all be treated as true for excel formulas.

Comment: That is correct but the way I like to phrase it is that zero is false and anything that is not false is true.